# PHPMailer to send email address verification email not working when REMOTE

Tags: php, email, outlook, smtp, phpmailer

I am trying to use PHPMailer to send a verification email and complete a new user request to my website.  When I test locally, everything works fine, and I receive the expected email from my outlook.com email account. However, as soon as I upload to my webhost server, it does not work.  Since I am using my outlook.com email, I cannot see where anything should need to change.  I contacted my host support and they don't have a clue.  Anyway, here is the response from my web host:

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-a2ss15.a2hosting.com ESMTP Exim 4.84 #2 Sat, 18 Apr 2015 11:31:25 -0400 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO williamsrn.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-a2ss15.a2hosting.com Hello a2ss15.a2hosting.com [75.98.175.95]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO williamsrn.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-a2ss15.a2hosting.com Hello a2ss15.a2hosting.com [75.98.175.95]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 HELP
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
CLIENT -> SERVER: bWljcm90ZWNjb25zdWx0aW5nQG91dGxvb2suY29t
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
CLIENT -> SERVER: d29ud29uKiEx
SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 Incorrect authentication data
SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Incorrect authentication data
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 a2ss15.a2hosting.com closing connection
SMTP connect() failed.
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Here is my php to process new user form request and send the email with PHPMailer:

```
<?php
/* REMOTE ONLY */
set_include_path(".:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/william5/php/includes");

include 'db_connect.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$fname = $conn->escape_string($_POST['fName']);
$lname = $conn->escape_string($_POST['lName']);
$coname = $conn->escape_string($_POST['coName']);
$email = $conn->escape_string($_POST['inputEmail']);
$hash = md5( rand(0,1000) ); 
$pass = $conn->escape_string(md5($_POST['inputPassword']));
$fullName = $fname . $lname;

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, corp_name, email, password, hash) "
    . "VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$coname', '$email', '$pass', '$hash')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
//echo "New record created successfully!<br>";


    $addy = "verifyEmail.php?qa=$email&qh=$hash";

    $message = "Hello $fname! <br>"
        . "Please click the link below to confirm your email and complete the registration process.<br>"
        . "You will be automatically redirected to a welcome page where you can then sign in.<br><br>"            
        . "Please click below to activate your account:<br>"
        . "<a href='$addy'>Click Here!</a>";

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

    $mail->isSMTP();                                        // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';                  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                 // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'xbox2112@outlook.com';               // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '********';                          // SMTP password I removed this for my privacy
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                              // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                      // TCP port to connect to
    $mail->From = 'xbox2112@outlook.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'GOD';
    $mail->addAddress($email, $fullName);                   // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('xbox2112@outlook.com', 'Information');
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                   // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Account registration confirmation';
    $mail->Body    = $message;                              //HTML Message  (if true)
    $mail->AltBody = 'alt body message';
try {
    $success = $mail->send();

    if($success) {
        echo "A confirmation email has been sent to $email with a link to activate your account. <br><br>Please check your email and select the link to complete your registration.";        
    }else{
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }

} catch (Exception $ex) {    
    echo $ex;      
}

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

What I don't understand is that nothing really changed (nor should it)as far as SMTP goes from my local to remote server but when I run the code remotely it does not work.  I added include_path at top for the PHPMailer package, but I know that is working because I require it just below.  I also need to change my database settings in db_connect.php, but I know that is also working because it creates the DB record.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks, John

Comment: BTW, the password field is actually my password, not ******.  I put that in there for my own privacy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ISP is redirecting you to their own mail server.

In your script you specify you want to connect to `smtp-mail.outlook.com`, but you are connecting to `a2ss15.a2hosting.com`, which I suspect is nothing to do with Outlook.com, but everything to do with a2hosting being your ISP. Read whatever docs are provided by your host, and open a support ticket with them to disable this redirection.

This is mentioned in [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

This is also exactly why you should enable encryption and verify certificates (the default in PHP 5.6, but not prior to that), because what they are doing is a man-in-the-middle attack, and is effectively revealing your password to this unknown (fortunately not too unknown in this case) third party.

Comment: +! You got my first +1! Very nice thank you.  Upon changing to a2ss15.a2hosting.com, everything worked fine.  I will look into encryption and verifying certificates.

Comment: Glad it worked. Don't forget to select it as your preferred answer too - click the tick next to the +1 button!

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't have enough point to comment I will tell you here. The problem might be with your authentication because you can connect to SMTP fine. Please do not paste what sent from and to the SMTP server because they are base64 encoded. That means you are revealing your username and password in base64.
If you decode `VXNlcm5hbWU6` you should get `Username:`. And your reply `bWljcm90ZWNjb25zdWx0aW5nQG91dGxvb2suY29t` will be decoded as `microtecconsulting@outlook.com`.

So, I think you need to change your password because you have revealed in your question. You might want to check your settings.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, and I will change my password.  However when looking at the decoded base64, my password is correct, yet I am still getting this error.

Comment: After alot of time, I realized that it was the very first line if the response: